# Why am I unable to remove nuget packages from a .NET project?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, nuget-package

I received the following task

> 1. Remove the nuget packages from MyProject (check other webapps):
>
> AspNetSprites-Core
>
> AspNetSprites-WebFormsControl

Since I am not too fluent in .NET-specific technicalities, I have been searching for a while to find these. I have been using Visual Studio 2015 to search for these and found them under *packages* in the project's file tree. After removing them and removing the following line from web.config:

```
    <add assembly="Microsoft.Web.Samples.ImageSprite" namespace="Microsoft.Web.Samples" tagPrefix="asp" />
```

I expected to successfully remove these from the project, but after I built the project the files reappeared under *packages*. What could be the cause of this behavior?

Comment: https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/tools/package-manager-ui#uninstalling-a-package...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they are NuGet packages you should just be able to go to tools->NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet packages for solution.

This will list all the installed packages for the project and you can uninstall them from here.

EDIT: Alternative solution from OP
That seems like a solution, but I already found out another one. I needed to remove the corresponding lines from packages.config

Comment: That seems like a solution, but I already found out another one. I needed to remove the corresponding lines from packages.config. If you edit your question with this alternative solution, I will surely accept it.